# Width/height listener breaks with "show window contents while dragging" disabled

Tags: java, windows, javafx, listener

I'm working on a GUI for a program (in JavaFX) that resizes all it's elements when the window resizes. When "show window contents while dragging" is disabled in Windows' performance options, the scaling in my width and height listeners doesn't trigger, so the elements stay the wrong size. Is there any way to work around or fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when "Show window contents while dragging" is disabled on Windows, Stage size is updated but not Scene size, so this can be fixed by using Stage size instead of Scene size.